# AWSのロードバランサーが正しく動かない

Tags: aws, nginx, amazon-elb

EC2インスタンスを2つ起動しています。
この2つは同じAMIから起動し、起動後は何も変更していません。
この2つをターゲットグループに指定したロードバランサーを作成しました。
ロードバランサーのDNSにアクセスするとどちらか一方にリクエストが飛ぶと思っていましたが、両方に飛んでいるようです。

プログラムとしては
http://[ロードバランサーのDNS]/testにアクセスすると
インスタンスのプライベートIPアドレスをdynamoDBに登録するようになっています。

ブラウザから1度 http://[ロードバランサーのDNS]/test を叩いた結果、各インスタンスのnginxのアクセスログが以下になりました。

```
[ブラウザに返って来る方のインスタンス]
172.31.7.1 - - [30/Jan/2021:06:27:49 +0000] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 200 1100 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36"

[ブラウザに返ってこない方のインスタンス]
172.31.7.1 - - [30/Jan/2021:06:27:49 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1104 "http://[ロードバランサーのDNS]/test" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36"
```

どちらかのインスタンスにしかリクエスト投げないようにしたいのですが、
何かわかる方いらっしゃいましたらご教示ください。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。
原因はfavicon.icoのリクエストでした。